# html not working for firefox but works for chrome

Tags: html

I have a template :

```
<font size="2" align="justify"><br/><br/>Some long message</font>
```

I get justify text in chrome but not in firefox. What might be the solution?

Comment: Don't forget that "font" tag is deprecated in HTML5. You should really use span or div instead of font. Also, font tag only had "color, face and size" attributes and align is not one of them as far as I remember.

Comment: _“What might be the solution?”_ – some basic tutorials on how this kind of stuff is done in _this_ millennium …?

Comment: Correct, when i saw the code it brought me back 20 years ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

Font tag is deprecated in HTML5 but also is always better to separate **structure (HTML)** and **presentation (CSS)**.

Use a `<p>` tag (paragraph) for adding long text.

```
<div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum  
</p>
</div>
```

Also the CSS property to justify text is `text-align:justify;`

```
div{
    width:500px;
}

p{
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

If you really have to use inline styles, you can:

```
<p style="text-align:justify; font-size:14px;">
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/undmcszz/5/

Answer (score 0):

The html font tag is deprecated. From w3schools website:

> Definition and Usage
>   The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
>   The `<font>` tag specifies the font face, font size, and color of text.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Use a supported HTML structure and style it with CSS:

```
<p>YOUR TEXT</p>
<style>
    p {
       font-size: 12px;
       text-alignment: justify;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I want to use inline css and I tried this <p style="font-size:12px; text-alignment:justify;"><br/><br/>Some long message</p> and it didnt worked

Comment: Also text-alignment:justify it's wrong. Use text-align:justify;